# Ps3 controller issue

Tags: ps3, controllers

My PS3 controller is dead and the cable to charge it broke.  I bought a new cable and it charges a wireless headset, but when I plug it into the controller nothing happens.  It won’t even turn on.  Does this mean my controller is no longer useable?

Comment: You should be able to use a usb cable to plug your controller directly into your PS3. Once plugged in, see if it works, else it is no longer useable.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, yes. There is a chance that the pins are just not making good contact, if the cord is new and it's not charging, the only way to fix that would be replacing the hardware in the charge port on the controller itself.